# using perl XML::LibXML to parse

Tags: perl, libxml2

I am using perl's XML::LibXML module to parse an XML response from a device. 
It appears that the only way I can successfully get my data is by modifying the XML response from the device. 
Here is my XML response from the device:

```
<chassis-inventory xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/10.3D0/junos-chassis">

<chassis junosstyle="inventory">

<name>Chassis</name>

<serial-number>JN111863EAFF</serial-number>

<description>VJX1000</description>

<chassis-module>

<name>Midplane</name>

</chassis-module>

<chassis-module>

<name>System IO</name>

</chassis-module>

<chassis-module>

<name>Routing Engine</name>

<description>VJX1000</description>

<chassis-re-disk-module>

<name>ad0</name>

<disk-size>1953</disk-size>

<model>QEMU HARDDISK</model>

<serial-number>QM00001</serial-number>

<description>Hard Disk</description>

</chassis-re-disk-module>

</chassis-module>

<chassis-module>

<name>FPC 0</name>

<chassis-sub-module>

<name>PIC 0</name>

</chassis-sub-module>

</chassis-module>

<chassis-module>

<name>Power Supply 0</name>

</chassis-module>

</chassis>

</chassis-inventory>
```

Here is the perl code I am using to parse and find the serial number for example:

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
my $f = ("/var/working/xmlstuff");
sub yeah {
my $ff;
my $f = shift;
open(my $fff,$f);
while(<$fff>) {
$_ =~ s/^\s+$//; 
$_ =~ s/^(<\S+)\s.*?=.*?((?:\/)?>)/$1$2/g;
$ff .= $_;
}
close($fff);
return $ff
}
my $tparse = XML::LibXML->new();
my $ss = $tparse->load_xml( string => &yeah($f));
print map $_->to_literal,$ss->findnodes('/chassis-inventory/chassis/serial-number');
```

If I do not use the regex substitution nothing is loaded for the script to parse. 
I can understand the stripping of newlines, but why do I have to remove the attributes from the XML response, so it only works if these lines:

```
<chassis-inventory xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/10.3D0/junos-chassis">

<chassis junosstyle="inventory">
```

Become this:

```
<chassis-inventory>
<chassis>
```

1. Is this a problem with the XML response or with the XML::LibXML module?
2. Is there a way to have it ignore the fact that there is empty lines in the file without using a regex substitution?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe it's probably failing because your XML lacks the proper header and doctype. That said this looks simple enough you might try XML::Simple which you can set to parse anyway even if the XML isn't 100% correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason your XPATH expression is failing is because of the namespace; you need to search in context to that.  Here's an explanation from the [XML::libXML documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-1.84/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod):

> NOTE ON NAMESPACES AND XPATH:
>
> A common mistake about XPath is to assume that node tests consisting
>   of an element name with no prefix match elements in the default
>   namespace. This assumption is wrong - by XPath specification, such
>   node tests can only match elements that are in no (i.e. null)
>   namespace.
>
> So, for example, one cannot match the root element of an XHTML
>   document with $node->find('/html') since '/html' would only match if
>   the root element  had no namespace, but all XHTML elements
>   belong to the namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml. (Note that
>   xmlns="..." namespace declarations can also be specified in a DTD,
>   which makes the situation even worse, since the XML document looks as
>   if there was no default namespace).

To deal with this, register the namespace, then search your document using the namespace.  Here's an example that should work for you:

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => '/var/working/xmlstuff');
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($xml);
$xpc->registerNs('x', 'http://xml.juniper.net/junos/10.3D0/junos-chassis');

foreach my $node ($xpc->findnodes('/x:chassis-inventory/x:chassis/x:serial-number')) {

    print $node->textContent() . "\n";
}
```