# Parsing SOAP response in perl with LibXML

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-libxml

I need to parse a SOAP response in perl:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header xmlns:iden="http://identifycaller.customermanagement.schema.amx.com"/>
   <soapenv:Body xmlns:iden="http://identifycaller.customermanagement.schema.amx.com">
      <ns2:Fault xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>ns2:server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Error interno del servicio. Por favor contacte al administrador.    </faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns2:InternalSystemErrorException xmlns:ns2="http://commonsexceptions.schema.amx.com">
               <ns2:errorCode>1049581</ns2:errorCode>
               <ns2:errorMsg>Error tecnico</ns2:errorMsg>
               <ns2:message>Error interno del servicio. Por favor contacte al administrador.</ns2:message>
            </ns2:InternalSystemErrorException>
         </detail>
      </ns2:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My code:

```
my $xml = $response->content;
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => (\$xml) );        

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
$xpc->registerNs('ns2', 'http://commonsexceptions.schema.amx.com');

my $errorCode = $xpc->findvalue('/*/ns2:errorCode');
my $errorMessage = $xpc->findvalue('/*/ns2:message');

print "Codigo $errorCode: $errorMessage\n";
```

I am unable to get the correct XPATH expression to get ns2:errorCode and ns2:message. I've read lots of answers and will continue playing with this but time is getting short.

I'm using perl 5.16 under windows but plan to deploy on perl 5.8.4 under solaris. I'm also using XML::LibXML.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using SOAP::Lite or XML::Compile::SOAP? They should take care of parsing SOAP responses for you.

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041719/using-perl-xmllibxml-to-parse/7042189#7042189

Comment: I tried SOAP::Lite but couldn't get to send params (always received null on the WS). So finally somebody shared with me a code making a direct request with LWP::UserAgent. So I went that way and now I want to parse the response. Haven't tried the other lib, I'll take a look

Comment: @Joel, looking at that answer is how I got to the current code. But still I've been unable to get the values.

Comment: @adrianmoya What if you remove the '*' from your XPath statement?  What does that give you?

Comment: @Joel It worked! I tried all sort of combinations, but finally, removing the * worked! Thank you! You can write that as the answer, if you could explain a bit why this change fixes the issue better. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm glad that removing the '*' from the XPath statement worked.  I believe I can provide a more detailed explanation.  Your original XPath statement was looking for `ns2:errorCode` and `ns2:message` one level underneath the root node.  By removing the asterisk from the XPath and using `//` shortcut to begin the search you're actually searching the entire document for any elements name `ns2:errorCode` and `ns2:message`.

One side note, this is actually less efficient as the parser has to go through all elements.  A more efficient XPath statement is `/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns2:Fault/detail/ns2:InternalSystemErrorException/ns2:errorCode` and `ns2:message`.  By specifying the full path you're telling the parser exactly where to look for your nodes.  Take a look at point #9 on [this page](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1018).

Comment: (You'll need to associate `soapenv` with the proper namespace using `registerNs`, of course.)

Comment: And ns2 has different URIs in different levels of the document, so will have to register and use something besides ns2 for one of them.